# Regex to match number of digits in a phone string?

Tags: regex, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Trying to put together regex that can match minimum 4 digits, maximum 16 digits, and those digits can be separated by characters: ()- x+ (but should not be part of the min/max count).

ie. "555-123-4567" would return true, "1-234" is true, "+44(55)123-3333" is true, "abcd1" is false, "1-()-4++++-()-6" is false.

Any way to do that with purely regex? Trying a couple expressions but not working.

Comment: Might be simplest to just make a copy of the string with nothing but the digits and then check the `length` of that.  `l = string.replace(/\D/g,'').length; if (l<4 || l>16) {... `

Comment: By your stated rules, `"1-()-4++++4-()-66"` should be true, not false. That's why this sort of validation should be done in code rather than a regex.

Comment: @CodeGnome oops, changed it. Should see 3 digits. In my current work it's seeing the characters between digits as part of the {4,16} count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need to do, is to match any number of the allowed characters, followed by a digit, followed by any number of the allowed characters, and match that same sequence between 4 an 16 times.

like this

```
^([()\- x+]*\d[()\- x+]*){4,16}$
```

http://rubular.com/r/6VhALkFPQZ

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
/^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$/
```

Works with these formats:

123-456-7890
(123) 456-7890
1234567890
123.456.7890

Comment: I need to include country code so that goes beyond 10 digits. And many countries don't even use the 10-digit format.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

The OP has already accepted a regex solution. Below I present an alternative way of looking at the problem. Hopefully it helps the OP, but it's really aimed more at future visitors and followers of [regex](/questions/tagged/regex).

### Don't Validate Logic with Regexps

Regular expressions work best for matching or extracting patterns, rather than for complex data validation. For example, the OP gives the following rules:

> Trying to put together regex that can match minimum 4 digits, maximum 16 digits, and those digits can be separated by characters: ()- x+ (but should not be part of the min/max count).

but then says that `1-()-4++++4-()-66` should be false. However, it meets the rules for truth as originally defined by the OP. (NB: This example was later changed in the OP's question, but the point I'm making remains valid.)

### Example: Using Code to Simplify the Regex Pattern Match

Logic should be encapsulated in short, testable pieces of code, not in complex regular expressions. For example, consider the following Ruby code:

```
numbers = [
  '555-123-4567',
  '1-234',
  '+44(55)123-3333',
  'abcd1',
  '1-()-4++++4-()-66'
]   

numbers.map { |num| num.delete '- x+()' }.grep /\A\d{4,16}\z/
#=> ["5551234567", "1234", "44551233333", "14466"]
```

Even if you aren't a Rubyist, the code should be easy to follow. This code strips out the characters that are irrelevant to our match, then checks that each string contains nothing but 4-16 digits anchored to the beginning and end of the string. Instead of validating a complex pattern, you're now just validating a simple pattern (e.g. all numbers) with a well-defined interval from 4 to 16. Furthermore, you can break this kind of logic up into smaller steps rather than simply calling long method chains, making this inherently more testable.

### Example: Avoiding Regexp Validation Altogether

You could even go further by avoiding the regex for any sort of validation, and making your Boolean expressions more explicit. Consider the following:

```
numbers = [
  '555-123-4567',
  '1-234',
  '+44(55)123-3333',
  'abcd1',
  '1-()-4++++4-()-66'
]

numbers.map do |num|
  digits = num.scan /\d/
  valid = digits.count >= 4 and digits.count <= 16
  puts "#{num}: #{valid}"
end
```

This will print:

```
555-123-4567: true
1-234: true
+44(55)123-3333: true
abcd1: false
1-()-4++++4-()-66: true
```

To me, this seems like a much more robust and flexible way of solving the "phone number validation" question, which gets asked here on Stack Overflow in one form or another with amazing regularity. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: > "but then says that 1-()-4++++4-()-66 should be false."
That was a mistake on my part in writing a question poorly. I edited the original question to make sense. 14466 should be true, just wanted 146 (aka. 3 digits) to be false because it didn't meet min-digit requirements. Just in the regex I was trying to write myself, 3 digits with alpha-characters was being seen as passing the min-4-char threshold, so I didn't know how to target the minimum specifically at digits when mixed with characters too. Thanks for your reply

Comment: I was looking for basic number validation solution I could quickly drop into some javascript. Eventually I'm going to replace it with a solution that expects a unique pattern for each country, where the user has to select the country code first, so it will be much more accurate at what input to expect.